# Numpy: Question about Matrix Multiplication

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

So I am using someone else's GitHub code, but we get different results for our matrix multiplication.

The GitHub Code has:

```
# d_norm is shape (67,)
# evec_hnl is shape (67,67)

result = d_norm*evec_hnl 

# result has shape (67,67)
```

But when I do the same code I get:

```
# d_norm is shape (60,)
# evec_hnl is shape (60,60)

result = d_norm*evec_hnl 

# result has shape (1,60)
```

I need my answer to be a square matrix with dimensions (60, 60), just like how in the GitHub code its a square matrix. Why do we get different results for the same code? What am I missing?

Comment: Tell us more about your variables.  Any `np.matrix`?

Comment: In my code, `d_norm` is a np.ndarray that is originally shape (60,60), but in the code they do np.sum(d_norm, axis=0) to do a column summation, resulting in the change in shape to (60,). The `evec_hnl` is a np.matrix of size (60,60). 

In the original GitHub code, both `evec_hnl`  and `d_norm` are np.ndarray

Comment: `np.matrix` does matrix multiplication with `*`.  `numpy` array does element wise multiply with broadcasting.